# How to merge an array of objects by key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have this object:

```js
[{
  "NOMOR_CB": "CB/20-0718",
  "ITEM": "ABC"
}, {
  "NOMOR_CB": "CB/20-0719",
  "ITEM": "A1"
}, {
  "NOMOR_CB": "CB/20-0719",
  "ITEM": "A2"
}]
```

I'd to merge the values of the same `NOMOR_CB` so the values of the same `NOMOR_CB` is combined. This is the desired output.

```js
[{
  "NOMOR_CB": "CB/20-0718",
  "ITEM": "ABC"
}, {
  "NOMOR_CB": "CB/20-0719",
  "ITEM": "A1, A2"
}]
```

How do I loop over the object to have the desired output?

My current loop (unable to combine the values):

```
var arr_test = "[";
$.each(response.arr_json, function(i, data) {
  arr_test += '{"NOMOR_CB":"'+ data.NOMOR_CB +'",';
  arr_test += '"ITEM":"'+ data.ITEM +'"},';
})

var test  = arr_test.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
test += "]";

document.write(test);
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am stuck at combining thevalues of same `NOMOR_CB`. I can do ordinary loop though

Comment: Note that *nothing* about this is JSON. You have an array of objects. I have edited the question as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` to summarise your array into an object. Use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array. You can `map` to form the desired object format.

```js
let arr = [{"NOMOR_CB":"CB/20-0718","ITEM":"ABC"},{"NOMOR_CB":"CB/20-0719","ITEM":"A1"},{"NOMOR_CB":"CB/20-0719","ITEM":"A2"}];

let result = Object.entries(arr.reduce((c, {NOMOR_CB,ITEM}) => {
  c[NOMOR_CB] = c[NOMOR_CB] || [];
  c[NOMOR_CB].push(ITEM);
  return c;
}, {})).map(([i, a]) => Object.assign({}, {NOMOR_CB: i,ITEM: a.join(', ')}));

let str = JSON.stringify(result); //Optional. Based on your code, you are trying to make a string.

console.log(str);
```

And dont concatenate strings to form a json. You can use `JSON.stringify(result);` to convert js object to string.

Doc: [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I haven't understand all of the script. Can I implement this in my current loop?

Comment: @Simba I would not advice you to concatenate your string to form a json. You can replace your loop with the code above. Let me know what you dont understand. Ill try to explain

Comment: It's actually for a report. the ITEM should combined as 1 row in the report. If not combined, there are two rows.

Comment: Please click on `Run code snippet` This will give you your desired output.