# How to manipulate this string and combine the values of the duplicate key?

Tags: jquery, string, loops

I have a string in a form of array of object.

```
var str_obj = `[
    {
        "STUDENT_ID": "ST001",
        "MAJOR": "SCIENCE",
        "STATUS": "1"
    },
    {
        "STUDENT_ID": "ST002",
        "MAJOR": "SCIENCE",
        "STATUS": "1"
    },
    {
        "STUDENT_ID": "ST002",
        "MAJOR": "HISTORY",
        "STATUS": "1"
    },
    {
        "STUDENT_ID": "ST002",
        "MAJOR": "MATH",
        "STATUS": "1"
    },
    {
        "STUDENT_ID": "ST003",
        "MAJOR": "HISTORY",
        "STATUS":"2"
    }
]`;
```

What I'd like to do is to manipulate this string and combine the values of the same `STUDENT_ID`. The output of the manipulated string should be:

```
var str_obj_combined = `[
    {
        "STUDENT_ID": "ST001",
        "MAJOR": "SCIENCE",
        "STATUS": "1"
    },
    {
        "STUDENT_ID": "ST002",
        "MAJOR": "SCIENCE,HISTORY,MATH",
        "STATUS":"1,1,2"
    },
    {
        "STUDENT_ID": "ST003",
        "MAJOR": "HISTORY",
        "STATUS": "2"
    }
]`;
```

The output is also should be in string with the format of array of object.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019522/how-to-merge-an-array-of-objects-by-key#50019678) great answer, but I still don't get it how to implement the solution since I have to manipulate string not array of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse` to convert the json (string) to array of objects. Use `reduce` to summarise the array into one object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into array again. `map` the array to join the `MAJOR` and `STATUS`

If you want your `str_obj_combined` to be a string, you can use `JSON.stringify`

And no need for `jQuery`. You can do this without any js library.

```js
var str_obj = '[{"STUDENT_ID":"ST001","MAJOR":"SCIENCE","STATUS":"1"},{"STUDENT_ID":"ST002","MAJOR":"SCIENCE","STATUS":"1"},{"STUDENT_ID":"ST002","MAJOR":"HISTORY","STATUS":"1"},{"STUDENT_ID":"ST002","MAJOR":"MATH","STATUS":"1"},{"STUDENT_ID":"ST003","MAJOR":"HISTORY","STATUS":"2"}]';

var str_obj_combined = Object.values(JSON.parse(str_obj).reduce((c, {STUDENT_ID,MAJOR,STATUS}) => {
  c[STUDENT_ID] = c[STUDENT_ID] || {STUDENT_ID: STUDENT_ID,MAJOR: [],STATUS: []}
  c[STUDENT_ID].MAJOR.push(MAJOR);
  c[STUDENT_ID].STATUS.push(STATUS);
  return c;
}, {})).map(o => {
  o.MAJOR = o.MAJOR.join();
  o.STATUS = o.STATUS.join();
  return o;
});


str_obj_combined = JSON.stringify(str_obj_combined); //Optional. Convert the array of objects into string

console.log(str_obj_combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

For you question, all you need is parse your string to array by using `JSON.parse()` method.

```
JSON.parse('[{"STUDENT_ID":"ST001","MAJOR":"SCIENCE","STATUS":"1"},{"STUDENT_ID":"ST002","MAJOR":"SCIENCE","STATUS":"1"},{"STUDENT_ID":"ST002","MAJOR":"HISTORY","STATUS":"1"},{"STUDENT_ID":"ST002","MAJOR":"MATH","STATUS":"1"},{"STUDENT_ID":"ST003","MAJOR":"HISTORY","STATUS":"2"}]')
```